# Firebase Authentication Crashing for version 11.8.0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Getting following error from firebase authentication using     com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0 for firebase authentication library. error caused after updating from 10.2.4

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.e com.google.android.gms.common.api.c.a(com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.bz)' on a null object reference
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdvv.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdwc.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzl.run(Unknown Source)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/396

Comment: Are you testing this on Emulator?

Comment: not emulator error got from Samsung Galaxy J2(2016), Galaxy J3 android version 6.0.1 and 5.1.1

Comment: obtained error after updating firebase version from 10.2.4 to 11.8.0

Comment: I generally get this error while using emulator.

Comment: devices with no play services or older version of play services may be the issue

Comment: Yes, it could be

Comment: Look in the logcat at the time the app initializes for this warning: `W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date`. The device or emulator must have a version of Play services installed that supports the version of the Firebase SDK the app is built with.

Comment: those errors are in production.